# Tkinter multi-line Text widget update

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
value.config(state='normal')     
value.insert(tk.INSERT,str(li[0])+'\n')
value.config(state='disabled')
```

I want to display some values from a list in the Text widget. Earlier I used Entry widget but it only showed the values in a single line but I want multiple values in multiple rows.

Earlier I used ScrolledText to solve the issue but I had to manually scroll down to see the new values.

```
value = tk.ScrolledText(frame1, width=12)
value.place(x = 240, y = 50, height=100)
```

Also, all the values were stored which made manual scrolling impractical as there are many values. I only want to display 5 or 6 values at a time in multiple rows which should automatically update with every new value and the oldest value should be popped out from the display.

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to ask a question. You tell us what you're building but don't say what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For inserting values form a list, alla ending in newline, you may do it like this:

```
value.insert(tk.INSERT, '\n'.join(str(x) for x in li))
```

as for updating the Text widget I don't quite understand what you are after. You can however find a good reference for managing the Text widget at: [The Tkinter Text Widget](https://web.archive.org/web/20200715112856/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Easier way to do. I usually do in irc chat similar Mirc.

You have `ScrolledText` on it. Then create function.

```
def Display_text(data):
    value.insert(tk.END, f'{ data}'+'\n' )
    return data
```

You have Entry on it. Then create function and bind . Then called `Display_text`.

```
def get(self, event):
    p =(entry.get())
    entry.delete(0, tk.END)
    Display_text(p)
    print(p)
entry.bind('<Return>', get
```